# Converting string to integer with python

Tags: python

When trying to convert a string into integer to be used as a variable later in the code, I get the following:

```
print int(urlsuccessful[i])

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2,919,247'
```

Comment: how about getting rid of commas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If only problems are commas, try:

```
>>> int("2,919,247".replace(",", ""))
2919247
```

Comment: One can also: #urlsuccessful[i] = re.sub(",","",urlsuccessful[i])
  #urlerrors[i] = re.sub(",","",urlerrors[i])

Answer (score 4):

[`locale.atoi()`](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#locale.atoi) will "demark" integers based on the current locale setting.

Answer (score 1):

`int` does not understand commas, you'll want to remove those before trying to convert

Answer (score -1):

You can just do

```
def int2str(my_integer):
  return "%d" % my_integer
```

Comment: Elaboorating on @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams' comment:  the return here will convert an integer to a string (and you could do that more easily with [`str()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str)), but the OP wants to convert a string to an int.